# How should I attach a pergola to my rooftop deck?

Tags: deck, decking, pergola

I know my sketch is pretty rough but I want to add a pergola like this to my rooftop deck. I obviously can't sink the posts into the ground. What is a recommended way of attaching the posts? I was thinking of using one of these [post brackets](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=deck%20post%20bracket&sprefix=deck%20,aps&rh=i:aps,k:deck%20post%20bracket) and then bracing it at the railing with additional L-brackets.

Also, I would like attach the ledger to the wall but it is hollow block. Is there a safe way to do that? I've heard it doesn't have much lateral "pull out" strength.

I'm pretty rookie so any advice would be great. My only other real project is that table and benches in the background there.

[image: My Pergola]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use titan post anchors for the posts.

[image: Titan Post Anchor]

For the ledger on the hollow block wall you can buy masonry anchors designed for that. Hilti makes tons of really good anchors. For hollow CMU walls, how they work is you drill the hole and insert a screen tube and fill it with the adhesive. Then when you insert the bolt it pushes the adhesive through the screen making it expand wider than the width of the hole.

**Hilti**

[image: Hilti Hollow Block Concrete Anchor]

**Simpson Strong Tie**

[image: Simpson CMU Anchor]